# Remove/Hide Blocks Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a majhong game.When I click two blocks with the same text I'm trying to 'hide' them, with the use of different className, but the code doesn't work. The variable `f` is used to keep a score of user's incorrect moves.

```
  f=0;
  function clicked(newDiv){ 
  var cl=0;
  if (newDiv.className=="clickedbox"){
    newDiv.className="boxed";
    cl=0;
  }
   else {
     if (cl==0){
       newDiv.className="clickedbox";
       cl=1;
      }
   else { 
       newDiv.className="clickedbox"; 
       var box=document.getElementsByClassName("clickedbox");

       if (box[0].innerHTML==box[1].innerHTML){
         box[0].className="removedbox";
         box[1].className="removedbox";
         cl=0;

   }
      else {
      f=f+1;
    }

  }
  }
 };


<style type="text/css"> 
.col-format {
 float: left;
 }

.boxed {
width: 10px;
padding: 10px;
margin:1px;
border:10px solid pink;
background-color: pink;
border-style:outset;
}
.clickedbox {
width: 10px;
padding: 10px;
margin:1px;
border:10px yellow;
background-color: yellow;
border-style:outset;
}

.removedbox {
width: 10px;
padding: 10px;
margin:1px;
border:10px green;
background-color: green;
border-style:outset;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can u put a demo on jsfiddle.net? How is class "removedbox" defined?

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable cl doesn't ever gets an value != 0 before you check it. You are setting it to 0 everytime before your first if statement checks for its value.

Try to initialize your variable outside the "clicked" function.